spawning from an event reader in Bevy
In the following code, I load a mesh and trigger some post processing code from the MeshLoading event, because it loads in parallel, meaning I can't access it synchronously from the same function that loads it.
If I also spawn it in the setup function, it does work, and the data from the post processing is generated and applied correctly, meaning it must get applied to the already spawned mesh, or that the spawn is delayed and runs in the same cycle as the post processing. I'm not sure which.
However if I spawn in the event reader function, it exists for one frame, and then the "unused" and "removed" events are emitted and the asset is dropped.
I am trying to understand why this is, and if it is possible to spawn after I have processed the data. The project ultimately will require me to load meshes, process the data, generate new meshes and spawn them.
use bevy::
    prelude::*
;
use material::MyMaterial;
use rand::Rng; // Add this to your imports

mod material;

const SHADER_ASSET_PATH: &str = "shaders/line_material.wgsl";
const PATH: &str = "monkey.gltf";

fn main() {
    App::new()
        .add_plugins(DefaultPlugins)
        .add_plugins(MaterialPlugin::<MyMaterial>::default())
        .add_systems(Startup, setup)
        .add_systems(Update, on_mesh_loading_event)
        .run();
}

fn setup(
    mut commands: Commands,
    // mut meshes: ResMut
    mut materials: ResMut<Assets<MyMaterial>>,
    asset_server: Res<AssetServer>,
) {
    let mesh_handle: Handle<Mesh> = asset_server.load(
        GltfAssetLabel::Primitive {
            mesh: 0,
            primitive: 0,
        }
        .from_asset(PATH),
    );

    println!("spawning from setup");
    commands.spawn(MaterialMeshBundle {
        mesh: mesh_handle,
        transform: Transform::from_xyz(0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
        material: materials.add(MyMaterial {}),
        ..default()
    });

    commands.spawn((
        Camera3dBundle {
            transform: Transform::from_xyz(0.0, 0.0, 5.0).looking_at(Vec3::ZERO, Vec3::Y),
            ..default()
        },
    ));
}

fn on_mesh_loading_event(
    mut events: EventReader<AssetEvent<Mesh>>,
    mut meshes: ResMut<Assets<Mesh>>,
    mut commands: Commands,
    mut materials: ResMut<Assets<MyMaterial>>,
) {
    for event in events.read() {
        if let AssetEvent::LoadedWithDependencies { id } = event {
            let handle = Handle::Weak(*id);
            if let Some(mesh) = meshes.get_mut(&handle) {
                let vertex_count = mesh.count_vertices();

                // random colors
                let mut rng = rand::thread_rng();
                let colors: Vec<[f32; 4]> = (0..vertex_count)
                    .map(|_| {
                        [
                            rng.gen_range(0.0..=1.0),
                            rng.gen_range(0.0..=1.0),
                            rng.gen_range(0.0..=1.0),
                            1.0,
                        ]
                    })
                    .collect();

                mesh.insert_attribute(Mesh::ATTRIBUTE_COLOR, colors);

                // println!("spawning from event");
                // commands.spawn(MaterialMeshBundle {
                //     mesh: handle.clone(),
                //     material: materials.add(MyMaterial {}),
                //     transform: Transform::from_xyz(0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
                //     ..default()
                // });
            }
        }
        else{
            println!("{:?}", event);
        }
    }
}
```

